# ORA-08103 Using global temporary table DML(insert, update, select) inside a procedure, select cursor to temp-table shows error object doesn't exists

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, cursor, temp-tables

Basically I need to modify data and store it in a temp table, delete the data every time the procedure is executed after exposing the data. The problem is that the temporary table used in a cursor as result of a procedure shows error

> object doesn't exist

I'm trying to get data from a global temporary table with a stored procedure, then truncate the data inside the stored procedure. I'm getting the "no longer exists" error from Oracle db, I tried 3 different ways:

1. Temporary table with `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;` statement, and `COMMIT;` at the end of procedure.
2. Temporary table with `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;` statement, and `TRUNCATE TABLE` at the end of procedure
3. Regular table with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE TABLE_NAME'` statement at the end of procedure

All of these options show the same error.

I have 2 tables and I am merging that 2 tables in global temporary table changing some values of records.

Then I am creating a cursor to return a `SELECT` to the temporary table.

It's here when the error appears.

So, I created the following tables:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE REM_ORDENSECCIONES_TPM (
    SE_CONSEC   NUMBER(38,0),
    SE_NOMBRE   VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),
    ET_CONSEC   NUMBER(38,0),
    SE_ORDENS   NUMBER(38,0),
    DI_CONSEC   NUMBER(38,0)
)
ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;
--
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE REM_ORDENSECCIONES (
    SE_CONSEC   NUMBER(38,0),
    SE_NOMBRE   VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),
    ET_CONSEC   NUMBER(38,0),
    SE_ORDENS   NUMBER(38,0),
    DI_CONSEC   NUMBER(38,0)
)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
--
CREATE TABLE REM_ORDENSECCIONESP (
    SE_CONSEC   NUMBER(38,0),
    SE_NOMBRE   VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),
    ET_CONSEC   NUMBER(38,0),
    SE_ORDENS   NUMBER(38,0),
    DI_CONSEC   NUMBER(38,0)
)
```

And I have this stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_OBTENER_SECCION_AMBULATORIO(etConsec NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
                                                    diConsec NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
                                                    cursorParam OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN
    --
    -- SE TRAEN TODAS LAS SECCIONES QUE ESTÁN EN PREGEVEN Y LAS QUE COINCIDAN
    -- CON LA ETAPA Y EL DIAGNÓSTICO EN SECCPREG
    -- SE GUARDAN EN LA TABLA TEMPORAL PARA PODER MODIFICAR EL ORDEN MÁS ADELANTE.

    --DEBUG
    -- SELECT * FROM REM_ORDENSECCIONES_TPM;
    -- SELECT * FROM REM_SECCPREG WHERE SE_CONSEC = 217;
    -- UPDATE REM_PREGEVEN SET SE_ORDEN = 11 WHERE SE_CONSEC = 217;
    INSERT INTO REM_ORDENSECCIONESP (SE_CONSEC, SE_NOMBRE, ET_CONSEC, SE_ORDENS)
        SELECT SE_CONSEC, SE_NOMBRE, ET_CONSEC, SE_ORDENS
        FROM REM_SECCPREG  
        WHERE SE_CONSEC IN 
                        (SELECT DISTINCT SE_CONSEC
                         FROM REM_PREGEVEN 
                         WHERE ET_CONSEC = etConsec AND DI_CONSEC = diConsec AND PR_ESTADO <> 'I') 
        OR ET_CONSEC = etConsec and Di_Consec = diConsec
        ORDER BY SE_ORDENS;
    --        
    -- ACTUALIZA LA TABLA TEMPORAL DE LAS SECCIONES CON EL SE_ORDEN
    -- DE LA TABLA DE REM_PREGEVEN.
    --

    --DEBUG
    -- SELECT * FROM REM_ORDENSECCIONES_TPM;
    -- COMMIT;
    UPDATE REM_ORDENSECCIONESP TMP
        SET TMP.SE_ORDENS = (SELECT DISTINCT PREGE.SE_ORDEN 
                             FROM REM_PREGEVEN PREGE 
                             WHERE ET_CONSEC = etConsec AND DI_CONSEC = diConsec AND PR_ESTADO <> 'I'
                             AND TMP.SE_CONSEC = PREGE.SE_CONSEC)
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM REM_PREGEVEN PREGE
                    WHERE TMP.SE_CONSEC = PREGE.SE_CONSEC AND SE_ORDEN IS NOT NULL);

 OPEN cursorParam FOR 
  SELECT SE_CONSEC, SE_NOMBRE, ET_CONSEC FROM REM_ORDENSECCIONESP;
--COMMIT; --COMMIT NECESARIO PARA ELIMINAR LOS DATOS TEMPORALES


  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE REM_ORDENSECCIONESP';-- || TBL_NAME;
END;
```

Any suggestion? I don't have any more paths to try.

I'm not Oracle expert, I used temporary tables with SQL Server and all was good.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Are multiple users running this procedure at the same time?  `ORA-08103: Object No Longer Exists` most commonly happens when a table is destroyed in the middle of being read.  Writers don't block readers, but a `TRUNCATE` is a DDL statement that effectively destroys and recreates the table each time.

Comment: The same user runs the procedure from a Visual Basic app. The procedure code is truncating the table after the returning cursor, at the end of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Temporary Tables in SQL Server are different from Global Temporary Tables in Oracle. Specifically, Global Temporary Table are **permanent** data structures it's just the data which is temporary. Data in a GTT is restricted to the session which inserted it, and will be wiped at the end of the transaction or session, depending on how the table is defined.

The other thing about your procedure is that it passes an opened ref cursor to the calling program. A cursor is not a data set, it is a **pointer** to a query: the calling program then fetches the data, which means it executes the query and processes its result set. The problem is, immediately after opening the query your procedure executes `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE REM_ORDENSECCIONESP';`. Consequently, when the calling program attempts to fetch records form the cursor the cupboard is bare.

Remove the `truncate table` statement. It is breaking your process. One of the problems with GTTs is that that issuing DDL is more troublesome than with normal tables: for instance we can't drop a GTT if there is an any session which has used it is still open. Fortunately truncation is almost certainly unnecessary, given the behaviour of global temporary tables. If you really think you need something, just `delete from GTT` at the start of the process; this will clear any lingering data from earlier in your session (transaction?) before you populate it afresh.

Here is a demo on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=654176c70d4ddb79129fab0a840dd8c2).

Comment: I'll try to truncate the table at the start of the process. I'll test `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS` GTT, without COMMIT statement too, Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Hi, thanks!, It works truncating the table at the start of the process, but only works with the regular table and the ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS table.

Comment: In the GTT `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;` doesn't work, shows the same error using the `COMMIT;` statement at the start of the process.


Now my question is, **what if 2 users execute the process at the same time?**, what data the process will show to each other?

I think that using GTT `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;` will show the data for each user session?

Thanks :)

Comment: @Cizaquita - try a DELETE rather than a TRUNCATE.

Comment: `DELETE` throws an error, `TRUNCATE` works fine, thanks! The answer is solved.

Answer (score 1):

If you created those tables, then they are accessible to you (and the procedure within your schema). On the other hand, the procedure uses some other tables - can you access them? Have a look at what happens when I run your code:

Tables are being created:

```
SQL> CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE REM_ORDENSECCIONES_TPM (
  2      SE_CONSEC   NUMBER(38,0),
  3      SE_NOMBRE   VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),
  4      ET_CONSEC   NUMBER(38,0),
  5      SE_ORDENS   NUMBER(38,0),
  6      DI_CONSEC   NUMBER(38,0)
  7  )
  8  ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;

Table created.

SQL> --
SQL> CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE REM_ORDENSECCIONES (
  2      SE_CONSEC   NUMBER(38,0),
  3      SE_NOMBRE   VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),
  4      ET_CONSEC   NUMBER(38,0),
  5      SE_ORDENS   NUMBER(38,0),
  6      DI_CONSEC   NUMBER(38,0)
  7  )
  8  ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

Table created.

SQL> --
SQL> CREATE TABLE REM_ORDENSECCIONESP (
  2      SE_CONSEC   NUMBER(38,0),
  3      SE_NOMBRE   VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),
  4      ET_CONSEC   NUMBER(38,0),
  5      SE_ORDENS   NUMBER(38,0),
  6      DI_CONSEC   NUMBER(38,0)
  7  );

Table created.
```

The procedure is created, but with some warnings:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_OBTENER_SECCION_AMBULATORIO(etConsec NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
  2                                                      diConsec NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
  3                                                      cursorParam OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
  4  AS
  5  BEGIN
  6      --
  7      -- SE TRAEN TODAS LAS SECCIONES QUE ESTÁN EN PREGEVEN Y LAS QUE COINCIDAN
  8      -- CON LA ETAPA Y EL DIAGNÓSTICO EN SECCPREG
  9      -- SE GUARDAN EN LA TABLA TEMPORAL PARA PODER MODIFICAR EL ORDEN MÁS ADELANTE.
 10
 11      --DEBUG
 12      -- SELECT * FROM REM_ORDENSECCIONES_TPM;
 13      -- SELECT * FROM REM_SECCPREG WHERE SE_CONSEC = 217;
 14      -- UPDATE REM_PREGEVEN SET SE_ORDEN = 11 WHERE SE_CONSEC = 217;
 15      INSERT INTO REM_ORDENSECCIONESP (SE_CONSEC, SE_NOMBRE, ET_CONSEC, SE_ORDENS)
 16          SELECT SE_CONSEC, SE_NOMBRE, ET_CONSEC, SE_ORDENS
 17          FROM REM_SECCPREG
 18          WHERE SE_CONSEC IN
 19                          (SELECT DISTINCT SE_CONSEC
 20                           FROM REM_PREGEVEN
 21                           WHERE ET_CONSEC = etConsec AND DI_CONSEC = diConsec AND PR_ESTADO <> 'I')
 22          OR ET_CONSEC = etConsec and Di_Consec = diConsec
 23          ORDER BY SE_ORDENS;
 24      --
 25      -- ACTUALIZA LA TABLA TEMPORAL DE LAS SECCIONES CON EL SE_ORDEN
 26      -- DE LA TABLA DE REM_PREGEVEN.
 27      --
 28
 29      --DEBUG
 30      -- SELECT * FROM REM_ORDENSECCIONES_TPM;
 31      -- COMMIT;
 32      UPDATE REM_ORDENSECCIONESP TMP
 33          SET TMP.SE_ORDENS = (SELECT DISTINCT PREGE.SE_ORDEN
 34                               FROM REM_PREGEVEN PREGE
 35                               WHERE ET_CONSEC = etConsec AND DI_CONSEC = diConsec AND PR_ESTADO <> 'I'
 36                               AND TMP.SE_CONSEC = PREGE.SE_CONSEC)
 37      WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
 38                      FROM REM_PREGEVEN PREGE
 39                      WHERE TMP.SE_CONSEC = PREGE.SE_CONSEC AND SE_ORDEN IS NOT NULL);
 40
 41   OPEN cursorParam FOR
 42    SELECT SE_CONSEC, SE_NOMBRE, ET_CONSEC FROM REM_ORDENSECCIONESP;
 43  --COMMIT; --COMMIT NECESARIO PARA ELIMINAR LOS DATOS TEMPORALES
 44
 45
 46    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE REM_ORDENSECCIONESP';-- || TBL_NAME;
 47  END;
 48  /

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.
```

So, what's wrong with it?

```
SQL> show err
Errors for PROCEDURE SP_OBTENER_SECCION_AMBULATORIO:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
15/5     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
17/14    PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
32/5     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
34/35    PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Aha; tables referenced in lines 17 and 34 don't exist (or I can't access them):

```
17          FROM REM_SECCPREG
34                               FROM REM_PREGEVEN PREGE
```

So, do they exist in your schema? If not, does someone else own them? If so, that user (owner) should grant you `SELECT` privilege (directly, not via role), and you should then either precede those table names with owner name (e.g. `scott.rem_seccpreg`), or create synonyms in your own schema.

See whether anything written above helps.

Comment: Yes, those tables exists in my schema, thanks to take the time to prove the code :), I think the preview asnwer is most focused in my problem.